# Add new column with tags computed from other columns Tags

Tags: dataframe, compare, calculated-columns

I hope the Title is fitting.
I have this data set
[Starting data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oHZo.jpg)

And whant to compare TypeX and TypeY so that the new column "Type" will result in (if one row has value missing the "Type" column will show A,B,C or D and if both TypeX and TypY is missing that row in column "Type" will show missing. Below is a picture that describes this:

[Goal data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr23n.jpg)

How do I compute this with character values into the wished for data frame in a efficient way. I am new to R and would appriciate your help